# asm embebido en C

Tags: .asmx

Antes bastaba con hacer

```
int main(int argc,char **argv){
  char f[]="cadena"
  asm("mov %0,%%rdi\n\t"
  "call puts\n\t"
  ::""r"(f):"rdi")
}
```

y funcionaba, pero ahora no. He intentado cargar el símbolo 
`__GLOBAL_OFFEST_TABLE_` (incluso desde `%rip`) sumar y restar offsets
de las librerias y llamar a `puts@PLT`. Pero solo funciona si hago

```
int main(int argc,char **argv){
char f[]="cadena"
asm("mov %0,%%rdi\n\t"
    "callq puts@PLT\n\t"
    ::"r"(f):"rdi")

  puts(cadena);  //es decir cuando fuerzo la carga de la biblioteca
   //en C
}
```

¿Alguna solucion?

Comment: Te sugiero que leas [Como hacer una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y formules una pregunta legible para el resto, de otro modo, cuesta mucho mas encontrar una solución a tu problema

Answer (score 0):

Primero que todo tienes que ponerle el `;` al final de la funcion `asm()` y luego debes compilarlo desde la terminal con `gcc <filename.c> -masm=intel -o name`